# How to get character position in alphabet in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, alphabet

I need to know the alphabet position of the n-th character in a text and I read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5927160/4438904) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927149/get-character-position-in-alphabet) but it does not work with Python 3.4.

My program:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import string

message = 'bonjour'
string.lowercase.index('message[2]')
```

It does not work with `ascii_lowercase` instead of `lowercase` too.

The error message:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Perso/WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4/python-3.4.3.amd64/Scripts/ESSAI.py',
wdir='C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Perso/WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4/python-3.4.3.amd64/Scripts')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-14-ba7faba5c581>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Perso/WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4/python-3.4.3.amd64/Scripts/ESSAI.py',
wdir='C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Perso/WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4/python-3.4.3.amd64/Scripts')
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Perso\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Perso\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Perso/WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.4/python-3.4.3.amd64/Scripts/ESSAI.py",
line 11, in <module>
    string.lowercase.index('message[2]')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lowercase'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get character position in alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927149/get-character-position-in-alphabet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string
message='bonjour'

print(string.ascii_lowercase.index(message[2]))
```

o/p

```
13
```

This will work for you, Remove the `'` in change index.

When you give `''` then it will be considered as a string.

Comment: The answer of print(message.lower().index(message[k])) is k I want to get the alphabet rank. So message[2] is n and the rank of n in alphabet is 14 not 2 ... ugh :/

Answer (score 4):

You might be shooting for something like

```
string.ascii_lowercase.index(message[2])
```

Which returns 13. You were missing `ascii_`.

This will work (as long as the message is lower case) but involves a linear search over the alphabet, as well as the importing of a module.

Instead, simply use

```
ord(message[2]) - ord('a')
```

Also, you could use

```
ord(message[2].lower()) - ord('a')
```

if you want this to work if some letters in `message` are upper case.

If you want the e.g. the rank of `a` to be 1 rather than 0, use

```
1 + ord(message[2].lower()) - ord('a')
```